# angular material display html in material textarea

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, textarea

I am looking for way to display html in material textarea.

I have something like this

```
<textarea matInput
  cdkTextareaAutosize
  [formControl]="bodyCtrl"
  #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize"
  cdkAutosizeMinRows="4"
  cdkAutosizeMaxRows="10">
</textarea>
```

the value of bodyCtrl is for example:

```
<span style="color:green">test<span>
```

and that's how it is rendered, but of course I need to display it as html tag with green content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As textarea only renders it's content as text, there is no way you can manipulate browser to consider the content as html. A workaround to this is to make use of `conteneditable` attribute with a div and render html with the help of `innerHTML` property. You can add personalized css to the div as per requirement.

```
<div contenteditable="true" [innerHtml]="bodyCtrl.value" ></div>
```